# Ionic 2, ControlValueAccessor interface issue

Tags: angular, ionic2

I created a custom component in Angular to search for google places like below, Code below is just to give you idea.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-googleplace',
  templateUrl: './googleplace.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => GoogleplaceComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class GoogleplaceComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
/* rest of stuff */
  writeValue(value: GooglePlaceStruct) {
    // sets the value
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn:any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }
}
```

And it works fine on the website, 
now i am converting the website into an ionic 2 app, when i use it with **ion-input, ControlValueAccessor interface methods are never called.**

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quite old:

Ionic replaces any `ControlValueAccessor` passed to `ion-input` with their own ([see here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/util/base-input.ts#L95)). This is the reason your `ControlValueAccessor` is never called.